Problem with Microsoft Orchestrator Hourly Scheduling
I've been using SC orchestrator for almost a decade now.
However, not until today have I needed to run something hourly and on the hour.
Presently, when I configure this, in the "Monitor Date/Time" activity I specify 0 days, 1 hour, and 0 minutes.
Then I check the "Starting" checkbox and enter 0 in the "minutes after the hour" field and press finish.
When I open the activity, I see that it's unchecked.
And when it runs, it'll run hourly starting at the time the runbook was started and not at the 0 minute mark.
How can I schedule my hourly job to run on the hour?
Nothing seems to work to keep the "0" minutes after the hour setting.
I have a workaround to run at the 1 minute after the hour mark, but that's not what we really want.
